# netcat client doesn't exit with error when tcp server has error

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, netcat

I want to compile some markdown posts thorough netcat. Here is `Makefile`.

```
# Makefile

all: $(POSTS)

$(POST_DEST_DIR)/%.html: $(POST_SRC_DIR)/%.md | $(POST_DEST_DIR)
  @nc localhost 3000 < $< > $@
  @echo 'compiled $@'

.DELETE_ON_ERROR: $(POSTS)
```

When TCP server exit with error, `nc` exit without error while Node.js `nc` wrapper exit with error. Here is a Node.js wrapper script.

```
// nc.js

var client = require('net').connect(3000);
process.stdin.pipe(client);
client.pipe(process.stdout);
client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

An then

```
# Makefile with nc.js

$(POST_DEST_DIR)/%.html: $(POST_SRC_DIR)/%.md | $(POST_DEST_DIR)
  @node nc.js < $< > $@
  @echo 'compiled $@'
```

The TCP server is also written in NodeJS. I want `nc` to exit with error when TCP server crashes in order to stop `make` process immediately.

Here is a TCP server for test.

```
// tcp server for error test

require('net').createServer(function(socket) {
  process.exit(1);
}).listen(3000);
```

I've read `nc` man page. But I found it's impossible to do what I want to do. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP doesn't have any concept of the remote server "crashing".  When a program with an open TCP socket ends (regardless of how), the OS will close the socket.

In order to do what you want, you would need to create a protocol where the server would acknowledge completion of whatever operation you want it to perform and then the client would exit with failure unless it got that application-layer acknowledgement.